# Fat Free Framework and websockets

Tags: fat-free-framework, phpwebsocket

I am trying to get the example located [here](https://github.com/f3-factory/websocket-example) to work. I have this on an Ubuntu server with apache 2.4.41 and PHP 7.4.3. I start the sample server using

`./websocket-server.php tcp://192.168.2.162:9001`

and it starts fine. Then on a client machine in the same subnet, I call the html page that is included with that sample and it connects

[image: Browser on client machine]

I have tried it on [websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) and it works as well.
[image: Websocket.org Screenshot]

When I open another ssh session with the server and run tcpdump, I can see the connection happened and that every time I send a message there is an exchange between the client and the server. These are the 2 packets after I click send on the client.

```
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
18:37:45.863086 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55343, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 70)
    192.168.2.200.63471 > 192.168.2.162.9001: Flags [P.], cksum 0x55a6 (correct), seq 2157957360:2157957378, ack 463051113, win 4113, options [nop,nop,TS val 1150020044 ecr 2015524271], length 18
E..F./@.@.............#).......i....U......
D...x"u...p.W.$.$.P.2...0.
18:37:45.863138 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30660, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.2.162.9001 > 192.168.2.200.63471: Flags [.], cksum 0x86e1 (incorrect -> 0xebc9), seq 1, ack 18, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2015640068 ecr 1150020044], length 0
E..4w.@.@.<E........#).....i...............
x$:.D...
```

The problem I have is that the client(s) never receive anything from the server and the only thing firing on the server is that the client is idling. It seems that the server can see the client connecting but it never sees the incoming message, or the event handlers are not registering? Is anyone familiar with a working example of websockets and the Fat Free Framework?

Any guidance is appreciated

```
Idling2020-12-11 18:34:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:34:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:35:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:35:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:36:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:36:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:37:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:37:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:38:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:38:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:39:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63372 idles
Idling2020-12-11 18:39:52 | 2.097 MB | Agent 192.168.2.200:63471 idles
```

Comment: Could you post code to your websocket-server.php example? Also your html file where the client interacts with the socket connection?

Comment: While I was typing my reply to you, I realized that this had issues with the namespaces. I guess I need to read up more on how they work. After cloning the repo in a new directory, it worked. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a classic "Talk to the duck" scenario. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging. Glad you got it working